# Google Cloud Storage bucket CORS policy is * for everything, yet I'm still getting CORS failures

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage

There are indeed a large number of CORS GCP Cloud Storage questions, but none solve my issue.

I am using a signedUrl, resumable, generated like this:

```
file.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'resumable',
    expires: Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000, // 60 minutes
    contentType: 'text/csv',
  })
```

I get the location from `res.headers.location` and use that to start writing chunks:

```
axios.put(res.headers.location, 'Hello World!', { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' } })
```

**This all works fine on the server.**

When I try to use that URL in the browser to do a PUT, it succeeds (in that the PUT returns a 200), but the browser generates a CORS error.

I have tried every possible permutation of CORS configuration I can think of.  I currently have it as permissive as possible:

```
user % gcloud storage buckets describe gs://my-bucket --format="default(cors_config)"
cors_config:
- maxAgeSeconds: 30
  method:
  - '*'
  origin:
  - '*'
  responseHeader:
  - '*'
```

I have also tried adding additional headers to the browser call, for example:

```
axios
  .put(
    url,
    'Hello World!',
    { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/csv', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } },
  )
```

The specific error I get is:

```
account-type:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at (the url) from origin (web client url) has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've added the origin, left it blank, added wild cards, put the headers I know are needed in responseHeaders, added every header in the universe to responseHeaders, make it a wildcard.

I don't know what to try anymore.

Preflight response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
access-control-allow-origin,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
https://my-site:3000
Alt-Svc:
h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-Length:
0
Content-Type:
text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:
Wed, 13 Dec 2023 22:29:25 GMT
Server:
UploadServer
```

PUT response headers:

```
Alt-Svc:
h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-Length:
0
Content-Type:
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:
Wed, 13 Dec 2023 22:29:25 GMT
Etag:
"ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c"
Server:
UploadServer
Vary:
Origin
X-Goog-Generation:
1702504413283130
X-Goog-Hash:
crc32c=/mzx3A==
X-Goog-Hash:
md5=7Qdih1MuhjZehB6Sv8UNjA==
X-Goog-Metageneration:
1
X-Goog-Stored-Content-Encoding:
identity
X-Goog-Stored-Content-Length:
12
X-Guploader-Uploadid:
(big long alphanumeric id)
```

Comment: Use the `inspect` feature of the browser. Make note of all request headers. Then use the CLI `curl` or Postman to create the EXACT same request. What are the HTTP status code and response headers? Remember, you must do the OPTIONS and the PUT methods. Post those details in your post. My guess is the `preflight` is failing in the browser.

Comment: Yes, the inspect feature shows me the preflight (OPTIONS) is working fine (200 response, no CORS error).  It is the PUT response (which is still a 200) that triggers the CORS error.  Indeed the PUT response has no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.  All I had to change was on the server side, when initiating the upload via the POST, I had to add the origin for the web server.  For some reason this origin is included in the appropriate headers for the preflight, but not the actual PUT.

I still don't know how (or if it's even possible) to initiate the upload (via the POST) on the client side - I can't make that work.

...but if you initiate it server side - after you generate the signedURL, you use that like this:

```
axios
    .post(url, undefined, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
        'x-goog-resumable': 'start',
        Origin: 'https://app.mysite.com:3000',
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.headers.location;
    });
```

...you then use the res.headers.location on the client side to do the PUTs for the file chunks.

Now that I know the answer, it is possible this could be considered a duplicate of:

[Google Storage API - Resumable Upload, AJAX, CORS Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281825/google-storage-api-resumable-upload-ajax-cors-error)

...although as a consumer of this information I think the starting point for either is different enough that having both questions up adds value.